# calling getaccount rpc method on foreign address

Tags: json-rpc

calling `getaccountaddress` method on an address associated with the default account return "" the name of the default account. The problem is calling `getaccountaddress` on foreign address that doesn't exist in the local wallet will return "" !

Shouldn't this method in the last case return an error or something ?

i think the solution here is to call `validateaddress` method to check this address `ismine` or not.

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The client only keeps indexes of the balances of addresses you own. There is no ability to query the balance of arbitrary addresses.

Comment: This is correct but completely irrelevant for the question.